# CSS overlay over the body of the page

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a DOM that looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <iframe id="content"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="overlayWrapper">
    <div id="overlay"><--THIS IS EMPTY DIV--></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Where inside the `main` div I have some other stuff too, which are not very relevant here. Now, these divs have the following CSS classes.

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 3000; // This doesn't seem to help.
}

#overlayWrapper {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000; // This needs to be at least 1000 for overlay to cover all elements in the page
  position: fixed; // This seems to cause the problem?!
}

#overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  will-change: opacity;
  transition: opacity 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Now, this seems to work to some extend, as I see my overlay with the `background-color` value of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` appearing on the screen.

The problematic part is that I cannot click on the stuff that are inside the `iframe`.

What I noticed is that this happens because of `position: fixed` style in the `#overlayWrapper`.

If I remove it, then I can click on the stuff from `iframe` but now the overlay is not visible any more.

Is it even possible to somehow keep the overlay but make the stuff on `iframe` clickable again?

I tried to add `z-index: 3000;` to iframe (i.e., to `#content`), but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index only works on [positioned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Which means the z-index that you applied to `#content`, which is the iframe, is not in effect.

```
#content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3000;
}
```

Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vymo9g8p/).

PS: I added some links in `#main` to simulate the content you might have on your page.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `z-index` property of the `div#main` element should be placed before the the `z-index` of the `div#overlayWrapper` element.

Comment: I tried setting it to `z-index: 5000`, for `#main`, it didn't help.

Comment: what do you want to achive?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: relative` on the `<iframe>` element because the `z-index` property gets in action with its relative.

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  /* This doesn't seem to help */
  z-index: 3000;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This solution works, I don't understand why this has been downvoted.